# sql select latest 10 entries before timestamp based on other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select the 10 previous log entries for each error by user:

```
table errors
    user, timestamp, status_code
    1, 2017-01-01 20:00, 404
    2, 2017-01-01 18:00, 404
    1, 2017-01-01 15:00, 401

table log
    user, timestamp
    1, 2017-01-01 19:55
    2, 2017-01-01 19:55
    4, 2017-01-01 19:55
    1, 2017-01-01 19:54
    1, 2017-01-01 19:52
    ...
```

E.g. There was an error for user 1 at 20:00. I therefore want to select the latest 10 log entries for user 1 before 20:00:

```
SELECT * FROM log WHERE user = 1 AND timestamp <= 20:00 ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 10
```

However, I want this to be done for all entries in the error table with status_code 404

Comment: select all from table log where exist in table errors and timestamp is less than the timestamp in errors table.

Answer (score 0):

By using Left Join You can get the values based on another table.
For Example:

> select a.*, b.* from first_table_name as a Left Join second_table_name As b On a.id = b.user_id where b.timestamp <= 'value'

This will solve your puzzle.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve the problem. The joined where clause on timestamp is not dynamic and a hardcoded value does not get me the resultset that I described in the question

Comment: Can you please share your query you tried with join. So i can tell you in more depth.

Comment: SELECT * FROM errors WHERE errors.status_code = 404 LEFT JOIN log ON errors.user = log.user WHERE log.timestamp <= ???

Comment: string (e.g. '2017-01-01 20:00')

Comment: mm have you tried it using between keyword Like ::: Between 'start' And 'end'

Comment: Because it would be harder for mysql to check if a string is lesser having time stamp with the field of date time.

Comment: The problrem is that it is not an explicit timestamp that I can write in the query. The timestamp should depend on the value of the errors table

Comment: Sorry, but i didn't get you here.

Answer (score 0):

You would use `ROW_NUMBER()` with a partition by the `user` column for this, but since MySQL doesn't support it you need to simulate it using variables:

```
SELECT user, timestamp, row_number FROM (
  SELECT @row_number:=CASE WHEN @user=user THEN @row_number+1 ELSE 1 END AS row_number,
    @user:=user AS user, timestamp
  FROM (SELECT log.*, errors.timestamp as error_timestamp
    FROM log
    JOIN errors on errors.user=log.user
    WHERE status_code=404) AS log_404,
    (SELECT @row_number:=0,@user:='') AS variables
  WHERE timestamp<=error_timestamp
  ORDER BY user, timestamp DESC
) AS ranked_log
where row_number<=10;
```

These blog entries explain the trick used for simulate `ROW_NUMBER()` in MySQL:

[MySQL – Generating Row Number for Each Row Using Variable](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/03/08/mysql-generating-row-number-for-each-row-using-variable/)

[MySQL – Reset Row Number for Each Group – Partition By Row Number](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/03/09/mysql-reset-row-number-for-each-group-partition-by-row-number/)